# Accessing data from JSON returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state, data-visualization

I'm doing a data visualisation in React with Recharts, with data from a static json file. When the user clicks on the Bar Chart, the value is passed to app, put in state (state.dayview[]) and I want to render the specific data for that specific chart area to the browser. Hence, I want to conditionally render the DayView component by matching the date from the full json with the date that was clicked on the chart.

I have the json in state (state.data) and I can log the state no problem. However, when I try to access specific data in the json object (ex: this.state.data.date), the value returns "undefined".
Below I have a map method that works fine, but the filter method obviously fails, as the "date" key is not being retrieved.
What am I missing??

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
            this.state = {
                data,
                dayview: []
            }
        }

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <div>
                    <StackedBarChart
                        data={this.state.data}
                        handleBarClick={this.handleBarClick} />
                </div>

                <section>
                    {this.state.dayview && this.state.data.filter(x =>
                        this.state.data.date === this.state.dayview.date).map(item => {
                            return <DayView
                                key={item.index}
                                date={item.date}
                                high={item.high}
                                low={item.low}
                                medium={item.medium} />
                        })
                    }
                </section>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

Here's a json-snippet, nothing weird here:

```
[{
    "date": "2016-12-13",
    "high": 3,
    "medium": 18,
    "low": 0
}, {
    "date": "2016-12-20",
    "high": 1,
    "medium": 27,
    "low": 0
}]
```

I really appreciate any input!

Comment: `(ex: this.state.data.date), the value returns "undefined"` it's clear that it didn't find the date that's why it's undefined. It should be dayview because I think the datview is array which has the date in an object

Comment: if `data` is an array `this.state.data.date` will not work.

Comment: Ah, data is an array. Could you guide me to a better way to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access a property of an object in the array like this `this.state.data.date`.
Javascript will look for `data` in Array, not in object inside `data` array.

To get to an object in Array you can do:

`this.state.data[0].date`.

But I believe you want to modify code:

```
<section>
  {this.state.dayview && this.state.data.filter(x =>
    x.date === this.state.dayview[0].date).map(item => {
    return <DayView
      key={item.index}
      date={item.date}
      high={item.high}
      low={item.low}
      medium={item.medium} />
  })
  }
</section>
```

`dayview` is an array that's why:

```
this.state.dayview[0].date
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you - that worked! Thanks for helping out a newbie.